# How can I manage two different cells in numberofitemsinsection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a collectionView with two different cells. The first cell should be displayed one time and the second should be displayed as often as the array is large. The result should be something like in the image in the attached link. Here is also a example code for better understanding my problem. Thanks to everyone who helps me!!!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    switch indexpath { // No indexpath in numberofitemsinsection!
    case 0:
        return 1 //display one time the first cell
    default:
        return images.count // display as often as the array is large the second cell
    }

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addImageCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

           cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row] 

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectedAtIndex = indexPath

        return cell
    }
}
```

[Here is the collectionView I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n026S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this inside `cellForItemAt` and you need to change `numberOfItemsInSection` like below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // return 1 more than our data array (the extra one will be the "add item" cell)
    return dataSourceArray.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // if indexPath.item is less than data count, return a "Content" cell
    if indexPath.item < dataSourceArray.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        // configure your ContentCell: cell. <attribute>

        return cell
    }

    // past the end of the data count, so return an "Add Item" cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddItemCell", for: indexPath) as! AddItemCell

    // configure your AddCell: cell. <attribute>

    return cell

}
```

For that you need to create a `ContentCell` and `AddItemCell` and also have a `dataSourceArray` to store all data you need.

Comment: Please add the minimal correct answer. I believe callback closures have nothing to do with answering the question.

Comment: Thank you for answering but this didn´t solve my problem.

Comment: You sure? I edited my answer so it's a bit more clear. In one of the comments you said youre having a `indexOutOfBounce` . You wouldn't get with this solution. My answer always displays the `AddCell` at the last `index`. If you want it to be the first all the time just change `indexPath.item < dataSourceArray.count`  to `indexPath.item == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 + theArray.count
}
```

Comment: You will also need to adjust the `indexPath.row` value to access the correct elements of `images` in `cellForRow`

Comment: I had the same idea to add the array.count by one but then I always get an error in cellforrow. How can I adjust the indexpath.row value in cellForRow. I always get fatal error: index out of range.

Comment: just subtract the offsets you don’t want. ‘indexPath.row - offset’ would do.